# Referencing Entity Framework in MVVM in layered architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

My app is layered in 4 layers:

- `Core`: where I put some general and interface classes.
- `Model`: where my code-first classes, and other related to domain, such as entity configurations and repositories etc.
- `Vm`: where the view models live. Referencing `Model`.
- `Desktop`: where the desktop app lives. Referencing `Vm`.

I have installed Entity Framework into `Model`, `ViewModel` and `Desktop`.

My question is: is it enough to install it into `Model` only? Why to repeat again?

[Edit]

- Here is my implementation of **Repository** and **UnitOfWrok** (
  **IRepository** and **Repository** will be on **Core**):

  ```
  public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
  {
     TEntity Get(int id);
     IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
     IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

     TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

     void Add(TEntity entity);
     void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

     void Remove(TEntity entity);
     void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
  }

  public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
  {
     protected readonly DbContext Context;

     public Repository(DbContext context)
     {
         Context = context;
     }

     public TEntity Get(int id)
     {
         return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
     }

     and so on...
  }
  ```
- Now, the new next interfaces and classed will be on **Model**

  ```
  public interface ICountryRepository : IRepository<Country> {}

  public class CountryRepository : Repository<Country>, ICountryRepository
  {
      public CountryRepository(CmsDbContext cmsDbContext)
          : base(cmsDbContext) {}
  }

  interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
  {
      ICountryRepository CountryRepository { get; }
  }

  public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
  {
      private readonly CmsDbContext _context;

      public UnitOfWork(CmsDbContext context)
      {
          _context = context;
          CountryRepository = new CountryRepository(_context);
      }

      public ICountryRepository CountryRepository { get; private set; }

      public int Commit()
      {
          return _context.SaveChanges();
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
          _context.Dispose();
      }
  }
  ```
- Now, in my ViewModel

  ```
  private UnitOfWork Currentunitofwork;

  Currentunitofwork = new UnitOfWork(new CmsDbContext());
  ```

I followed a description of a tutor in udemy.

Is this separation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all repository (Entity framework) methods behind interfaces in the Core and reference those interfaces in the ViewModel project.

Core.dll

```
public class SomeModel {}

public interface ISomeModelRepositoryService
{
    SomeModel GetById(int id);
    void Save(SomeModel model);
}
```

Model.dll - this project implements Core's interfaces and contains only database methods (Entity framework in your case)

```
public class SomeModelRepositoryService : ISomeModelRepositoryService
{
    public SomeModel GetById(int id)
    {
        //Entity framework code
    }

    public void Save(SomeModel model)
    {
        //Entity framework code
    }
}
```

ViewModel.dll

```
public class SomeModelViewModel
{
    private ISomeModelRepositoryService _RepositoryService;

    public SomeModel Model { get; set; }

    public SomeModelViewModel(ISomeModelRepositoryService repositoryService)
    {
        _RepositoryService = repositoryService;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _RepositoryService.Save(this.Model);
    }
}
```

Create repository implementation instances in top startUp project(Main method for example) and put it to ViewModel as parameters:

```
ISomeModelRepositoryService repositoryService = new SomeModelRepositoryService();

SomeModelViewModel viewmodel = new SomeModelViewModel(repositoryService);
```

With this approach only "Model.dll" need to have references to Entity Framework

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify this. **Repositories interfaces** will be moved to **Core**, but **Inherited Repositories** will stay in **Model**. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, because as I understand your business logic which use repositories is in the `Core`.

Comment: This will create **circular dependency**!. If the **Repositories interfaces** moved to **Core**, means **Core** must have reference to **Model**. In the other side, the **inherited repositories** in **Model** can't reach the **interfaces**. Got confused!

Comment: Please, see my code example. `Core` has defined interfaces which `Core`s other classes use. `Core` know nothing about `Repositories`. `Repositories` know about Core and implements interfaces.

Comment: I hope if you check my last edit about how I did implement Repository and UnitOfWork. Thanks.

Comment: It is little bid different from my example. I advise you to ask your question in [CodeReview stack](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)